# Parsing EKEvent description text

Tags: parsing, ekevent

I am currently working on an iOS application that uploads an EKEvent's `event.description` that is a basic NSString.

Problem is, when I download the file from my server after uploading it, parsing the string is a hassle.

Currently, this is the string im looking at when I have downloaded the text file

`"EKEvent <0x9dd50b0> {EKEvent <0x9dd50b0> {title = Another Event SC; location = A House; calendar = EKCalendar <0x994e7f0> {title = Calendar; type = Local; allowsModify = YES; color = #0E61B9;}; alarms = (null); URL = (null); lastModified = 2013-04-11 20:44:58 +0000; timeZone = (null)}; location = A House; startDate = 2012-10-11 07:00:00 +0000; endDate = 2012-10-13 06:59:59 +0000; allDay = 1; floating = 1; recurrence = (null); attendees = (null)}"`

I figured parsing this file wouldn't be bad but I am fairly new to objective C.

Here's what I have done so far

```
NSString *anotherString = [NSString stringWithFormat:components[i]];
NSLog(@"%@", anotherString);

//EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
//EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

NSArray *totalEventInfo = [anotherString componentsSeparatedByString:@"= "];

NSLog(@"%@",totalEventInfo);
```

Assume `anotherString` contains the downloaded text file string displayed earlier. Heres the output after seperating the string and storing each seperated string into incremental components of totalEventInfo.

```
"EKEvent <0x9dbe430> {EKEvent <0x9dbe430> {title ",
"Another Event SC; location ",
"A House; calendar ",
"EKCalendar <0x99e9570> {title ",
"Calendar; type ",
"Local; allowsModify ",
"YES; color ",
"#0E61B9;}; alarms ",
"(null); URL ",
"(null); lastModified ",
"2013-04-11 20:44:58 +0000; timeZone ",
"(null)}; location ",
"A House; startDate ",
"2012-10-11 07:00:00 +0000; endDate ",
"2012-10-13 06:59:59 +0000; allDay ",
"1; floating ",
"1; recurrence ",
"(null); attendees ",
"(null)}"
```

)

How do I go about specifying a domain of a string? Ex. Read in from a string, a string of characters from a character '=' and ending at the next ';'.

Maybe this isnt a good way to go about parsing the information.

I was thinking instead of uploading a file that hold the event.description of an EKEvent, I would upload a file with event.title, event.startdate, event.enddate, etc. rather than event.description and having to parse the file everytime downloaded.

Suggestions or opinions are appreciated :)